# My string of if elif and else statements aren't working and I have no clue why

Tags: python

I am trying to make it so the characters in the word are each run through a program that changes it to a different character if it's a vowel. This is the code.

```
    word = input(";")
for ch in word:
    if ch == " ":
        ch = "~"
    elif ch == "a":
        ch = "0"
    elif ch == "e":
        ch = "1"
    elif ch == "i":
        ch = "2"
    elif ch == "o":
        ch = "3"
    elif ch == "u":
        ch = "4"
    elif ch == "A":
        ch = "5"
    elif ch == "E":
        ch = "6"
    elif ch == "I":
        ch = "7"
    elif ch == "O":
        ch = "8"
    if ch == "U":
        ch = "9"
    else:
        print("ButtChin", end=" ")
```

I tried an if elif else string to test each vowel as they ran through the for loop. It supposed to change the word so if it read "out" it would read something like "34t". Instead, it didn't even read the statement I made and went straight to the fail safe I made to see if it was even running through or not.

Comment: Setting `ch = "0"` does not change `word`. Strings are immutable in python, you need to make a new string. You should consider using a dictionary instead and looking up the characters.

Answer (score 2):

When you assign to `ch` in the loop, you're doing nothing.

Consider:

```
>>> foo = "foo"
>>> for ch in foo:
...     ch = "g"
... 
>>> foo
'foo'
```

Also, at the end this is a separate conditional:

```
    if ch == "U":
        ch = "9"
    else:
        print("ButtChin", end=" ")
```

And your test case of `"out"` doesn't have any uppercase `U`s so of course you get the else clause executing each time. I suspect you meant for this to be:

```
    elif ch == "U":
        ch = "9"
    else:
        print("ButtChin", end=" ")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. I feel like a numb nut, especially with the ch situation.

Comment: Don't worry about it!  We all started off where you are.  You'll get there!